# Express: receiving a router instance vs creating one on routes file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm grasping the basis of Express, and I'm wondering whether there's a difference or a standard choice with an objective reason for choosing one of these approaches when dealing with routes:

```
import { Router } from 'express';

const router = new Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'));

export default router;
```

VS

```
export default function(router) {
    router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'));
}
```

The first approach I took from the [mern.io](http://mern.io) stack, and the second one from the [krakenjs](http://krakenjs.com) example.

At first glance (and having a OOP background) it looks like the second approach is designed for dependency injection; but since we're talking about javascript, I'm not sure the first one isn't. Also I'm not sure how testing is done, so maybe both cases are testables.

Any insights regarding which approach is considered the standard way and why would be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone finding this later, I would say that the first approach is considered the "standard" in Express v4 (the version where Router instances were introduced). One of the benefits of using a Router instance is being able to isolate some of your middleware to a per-router instance level, hence declaring the router instance alongside your routes in a file. You can then add any middlewares to just that specific router instance. I think the Krakenjs approach has more to do with the specific implementation of kraken as a library that adds functionality by default.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a lots of routers of different namespaces for example in `Router`  directory of your project so each file in this directory name like `userRouters` or `profileRouters` depend on the namespace and content will be like this:

```
var theNamespace='user';
export default function(router) {
  router.get(theNamespace+'/login', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'));
```

}

then you dont need to write all routers in one file without namespace in your server file just require each file in `Router` directory like this:

```
// read Router directory files here synchronously
for(var file in routerFiles){
  require('./Routers/'+file)(router)
}
```

its not a great benefit but in big projects that rout handlers get increase it will be helpful

Comment: I'm still kind of confused as I am unable to grasp the benefit of doing it this way. To my (basic, entry-level) knowledge you can get the same results by calling `app.use('/users', require('./users/route')` and not passing the router as a parameter.  I fail to see the benefit as testability seems not to be the thing at stake. Could you provide a more dense example so I can understand the benefit, please?  Thanks in advance!